# Correct way to use parameters within Groovy SQL

Tags: mysql, json, groovy

I am using Groovy SQL to execute a query which adds some JSON to an array in my Postgres JSONB database.

When I run the code below, I get a warning about SQL injection, the warning I get is below.

> In Groovy SQL please do not use quotes around dynamic expressions
>   (which start with $) as this means we cannot use a JDBC
>   PreparedStatement and so is a security hole. Groovy has worked around
>   your mistake but the security hole is still there.

Also I can't save the JSON in my database if there is a ' character in my JSON, I get the below error:

> Sql failed to process query unterminated ' character

```
@Override
Operation save(Player player) {
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(player)
    Blocking.get {
        sql.executeUpdate("""
            UPDATE site_content
            SET content = jsonb_set(content, '{playersContainer,players}'::text[], content->'playersContainer'->'players' || '${json}'::jsonb)
            where id = :id
            """,id: player.teamId)
    }.operation()
}
```

I have changed the code to this

```
@Override
Operation save(Player player) {
    String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(player)
    Blocking.get {
        sql.executeUpdate("""
            UPDATE site_content
            SET content = jsonb_set(content, '{playersContainer,players}'::text[], content->'playersContainer'->'players' || ':json'::jsonb)
            where id = :id
            """, json: json, id: player.teamId)
    }.operation()
}
```

But I get the error

> Detail: Expected JSON value, but found ":".   Position: 167

What is the correct way to place dynamic parameters into my Groovy SQL queries? And should I have to encode the JSON when I send it to the query? At the moment before I send it from my React app, I do JSON.stringfy(json) is this not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shall not be quotes around a binding name.

Use `:json` instead of `':json'`.

The first is binding, the second is a string starting with a colon. So the error message is straightforward about that: unable to parse a json object from string `':json'`.